# Contour integration: $ \int_{|z|=3} \frac{e^{2z}}{z^5} dz $

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Let $\gamma$ be the closed circle given by $|z|=3$. Evaluate 
>   $$
> \int_\gamma \frac{e^{2z}}{z^5} dz
> $$

How do I evaluate this? I set $z=3e^{i\theta}$, but I don't know how to work with the $e^{2z}$ term in the integrand.

Comment: Hint: residue theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), which implies that

$$f^{(4)}(0) = \frac{4!}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^5} dz$$

Now choose $f(z) = e^{2z}$ and compute some derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Express $f(z)=\mathrm{e}^{2z}/z^5$ as a Laurent series, i.e.
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-5}^\infty a_nz^n.
$$
Then, the value of the integral should be $2\pi ia_{-1}$, using Residue Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

In a neighbourhood of the origin we have:
$$ e^{2z} = 1+2 z+2 z^2+\frac{4 z^3}{3}+\frac{2 z^4}{3}+\frac{4 z^5}{15}+O(z^6), \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \frac{e^{2z}}{z^5} = \frac{1}{z^5}+\frac{2}{z^4}+\frac{2}{z^3}+\frac{4}{3 z^2}+\color{red}{\frac{2}{3 z}}+\frac{4}{15} + g(z), \tag{2}$$
with $g(z)$ being a holomorphic function. The residue theorem then gives:
$$ \oint_{\gamma}\frac{e^{2z}}{z^5}\,dz = \color{red}{\frac{4\pi i}{3}}.\tag{3}$$